# Trim strings in the column with same pattern

Tags: arrays, r, string, trim, data-manipulation

I have a column populated with string with same pattern *.stage1. I want to grab every string, copy every string to another column as a bullet point; trim out ".stage1" and populate the first column with the every character before ".stage1".

This will save a lot of time, can you suggest a package that can help me create this script?

Thanks,
Mago

Comment: Could you provide sample data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copying the column should not be an issue.  You can make the altered version with `sub`.

```
## Some sample data
df = data.frame(x = paste0("A", 1:9, ".stage1"))
> df
          x
1 A1.stage1
2 A2.stage1
3 A3.stage1
4 A4.stage1
5 A5.stage1
6 A6.stage1
7 A7.stage1
8 A8.stage1
9 A9.stage1

df$x2 = df$x
df$x = sub("(.*)\\.stage1", "\\1", df$x)
df
   x        x2
1 A1 A1.stage1
2 A2 A2.stage1
3 A3 A3.stage1
4 A4 A4.stage1
5 A5 A5.stage1
6 A6 A6.stage1
7 A7 A7.stage1
8 A8 A8.stage1
9 A9 A9.stage1
```

Some extra detail on the `sub` statement.
`sub` will replace everything matching the first expression with the second one. What are those expressions?

First expression:   "(.*)\\.stage1"
. matches any character.
.* matches any number of characters.
Because .* is in parentheses, whatever it matches will be stored in a variable called \1.
So "(.*)\\.stage1" will match the string ".stage1" and everything before it storing the characters before .stage1 in \1.

Second expression: "\\1"
We want to replace this with just the characters before, so the replacement string is "\\1".

Answer (score 0):

You can do it directly with `str_match` from `stringr`:

```
library(stringr)

x <- paste0("A", 1:9, ".stage1") # sample data

str_match(x, "(.*)\\.stage")

     [,1]       [,2]
 [1,] "A1.stage" "A1"
 [2,] "A2.stage" "A2"
 [3,] "A3.stage" "A3"
 [4,] "A4.stage" "A4"
 [5,] "A5.stage" "A5"
 [6,] "A6.stage" "A6"
 [7,] "A7.stage" "A7"
 [8,] "A8.stage" "A8"
 [9,] "A9.stage" "A9"
```

The values inside the parenthesis capture the first part of the string, so when you call `str_match` it returns the full string plus a column with the captured value.